# Finding $a_n$ if $a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$ with $a_1=2$ and $a_2=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $a_1=2,\; a_2=3,\; a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$.

How can i prove that:  $a_n=2^{n-1}+1$

I Tried to isolate $a_n$ but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you to solve the recurrence equation or just to verify the expression is correct?

Comment: i need to solve

Comment: you are right, sorry for that. i changed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general method to solve the recursion $$a_{n+1}=\color{green}{\bf 3}a_n-\color{green}{\bf 2}a_{n-1},$$ is to consider the characteristic equation $$r^2=\color{green}{\bf 3}r-\color{green}{\bf 2},$$ whose roots are $r=\color{red}{\bf1}$ and $r=\color{red}{\bf2}$ hence there exists $A$ and $B$ such that, for every $n$, $$a_n=A\cdot\color{red}{\bf2}^n+B\cdot\color{red}{\bf1}^n=A\cdot2^n+B.$$
The initial conditions yield $A$ and $B$.

In full generality, the characteristic equation of the recurrence $$a_{n+1}=\color{green}{\mathbf b_1}a_n+\color{green}{\mathbf b_2}a_{n-1}+\cdots+\color{green}{\mathbf b_k}a_{n-k+1},$$ is the polynomial identity $$r^k=\color{green}{\mathbf b_1}r^{k-1}+\color{green}{\mathbf b_2}r^{k-2}+\cdots+\color{green}{\mathbf b_k}.$$

Comment: didn't understand how do you find $A,B$.

Comment: As said in the answer, this uses the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: got it thanks that's a nice one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n} &= 2({a_n} - {a_{n - 1}}) \to {a_n} - {a_{n - 1}} = {2^{n - 1}} \\
{a_n} &= {a_{n - 1}} + {2^{n - 1}} \\
&= {a_{n - 2}} + {2^{n - 1}} + {2^{n - 2}} \\
&= \cdots \\ 
&= {a_1} + {2^{n - 1}} + {2^{n - 2}} +  \cdots  + {2^1} \\
&= 2 + {{{2^{n - 1}} - 1} \over {2 - 1}} \\
&= {2^{n - 1}} + 1
\end{align}

**Or:**

\begin{align}
{a_{n + 1}} - 2{a_n} &= {a_n} - 2{a_{n - 1}} \to {a_n} - 2{a_{n - 1}} = {a_2} - 2{a_1} =  - 1 \\
{a_n} - 1 &= 2({a_{n - 1}} - 1) \\
&= {2^2}({a_{n - 2}} - 1) \\
&=  \cdots  \\
&= {2^{n - 1}}({a_1} - 1) \\
&= {2^{n - 1}} \Longrightarrow a_n=2^{n - 1} + 1
\end{align}

But how can we get the coefficient in front of $a_n$?

-- let $t=a_n=a_{n-1}=\cdots=a_{n-k}$ then solve the $t$

Comment: how come $a_n-a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$?

Comment: @roy Let :$b_n=a_n-a_{n-1} , b_{n+1}=2b_n \Longrightarrow b_n $ is a geometric sequence $ \Longrightarrow b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}=(a_2-a_1) \cdot 2^{n-1} $

Comment: got it thanks a lot

Comment: in the hint i didnt understan the stage from $a_{n-1}$ to $a_{n-2}$

Comment: @roy $$a_{n}-1=2(a_{n-1}-1) \\
a_{n-1}-1=2(a_{n-2}-1) \\
So,~~ a_{n}-1=2^2(a_{n-2}-1)=\cdots
$$

Comment: great i see it know

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=3a_n-2a_{n-1}\\
a_{n+1}-a_n&=2(a_n-a_{n-1})\\
u_{n+1}&=2u_n\end{align}$$
where $u_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$

Given $a_1=2, a_2=3$, we have

$$\begin{align}
u_2&=a_2-a_1&=1\\
u_3&=a_3-a_2&=2\cdot 1 = 2\\
u_4&=a_4-a_3&=2\cdot 2 = 4\\
\vdots\\
u_n&=a_n-a_{n-1}&=2\cdot 2^{n-3}=2^{n-2}\end{align}$$

Summing and telescoping gives 
$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}a_n-\cancelto{2}{a_1}&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}2^{r-1}\\
&=\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2-1}\\
&=2^{n-1}-1\\
a^n&=2^{n-1}+1\end{align}$$

Comment: I thought this might be a helpful way to illustrate the neat  telescope approach. However, there has been two downvotes without any comments, which is disheartening. Would appreciate constructive comments if there are errors or any other points to note. Thanks.